# Definition of double cover

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading about Riemann surfaces and in case a surface X is hyperelliptic, there must be a double cover $X\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$

What does it mean to say that the map $X\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ is double cover?

Thanks

Comment: It is a cover of 2 sheets, most likely connected.

Comment: This is not correct. There's a double cover $X\to\Bbb P^1$. Covering maps have to map from something $k$-dimensional to something $k$-dimensional. You're confusing things with the canonical mapping (given by the canonical line bundle or linear series) to $\Bbb P^{g-1}$.

Comment: Start here if you need to:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

Comment: @TedShifrin, You're right. I had mistaken the canonical map. Thank you.

Comment: @jgon: The OP revised the question.  In fact, the canonical mapping to $\Bbb P^{g-1}$ double-covers a rational normal curve (which is a $\Bbb P^1$) in $\Bbb P^{g-1}$.